# Facebook Graph API: ask user to which page is used for feed posting?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing a custom application to automatically post to my business Facebook page.
I've created a new app profile and got the API key and secret key and know how to post to my Facebook page automatically using graph API.

My Code:

```
FB.init({ appId: "My FB API ID", status: true, cookie: true, frictionlessRequests: true });
FB.login(function (response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
           var acc_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
           FB.api('/me/accounts', 'GET', '', function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  if (!response || response.error) {
                      alert(JSON.stringify(response.error)); 
                  }
                  else {
                       if (response.data.length > 0) { //-- Check for page list
                           acc_token = response.data[0].access_token; //== Change Accesstoken If a page is exist
                          }
                          var data = {
                              name: "Automatically Feed Posting",
                              link: "www,example,com", 
                              access_token: acc_token,
                              description: "Hello, it's for testing"
                          }

                          FB.api('me/feed', 'post', data, function (response) {
                                  if (!response || response.error) {
                                     alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));                                                    
                                  }
                                  else {
                                      alert("Your Feed Successfully Posted");
                                  }
                             });
                      }
              });
          }                                
      }, { scope: 'email,user_likes,publish_actions,publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages,rsvp_event' });
```

The problem is: If a user have more than one Page, and requesting to `'/me/accounts'`, i got list of all pages. Here i want to first ask to user which page he want to used for automatically posting. 
(In current senior/above code i fetch first index of page list and use this for posting).

**Updated:**

After doing some googling ...I found many post, they all suggested to save/ask user to for their `page's Id` manually(before doing posting) and use this page id when get all pages list and comparing this pageId with list and perform further actions.

For Example:

```
var Userpage_id = "1234567890";
        FB.init({ appId: "My FB API ID", status: true, cookie: true, frictionlessRequests: true });
        FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        var acc_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        FB.api('/me/accounts', 'GET', '', function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            if (!response || response.error) {
                                alert(JSON.stringify(response.error)); 
                            }
                            else {
                                if (response.data.length > 0) { //-- Check If page list
                                for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++ ) {
                                    if(response.data[i].page_id == Userpage_id) {
                                        acc_token = response.data[0].access_token; //== Change Accesstoken If a page is exist
                                        }
                                    }                                    
                                }

                                var data = {
                                    name: "Automatically Feed Posting",
                                    link: "www,example,com", 
                                    access_token: acc_token,
                                    description: "Hello, it's for testing"
                                }
                                FB.api('me/feed', 'post', data, function (response) {
                                    if (!response || response.error) {
                                        alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));                                                    
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        alert("Your Feed Successfully Posted");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }                                
                }, { scope: 'email,user_likes,publish_actions,publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages,rsvp_event' });
```

But i don't like to do this, there is any method to display all pages list to user(don't put pageid manually)and after selecting page perform posting?

**Updated:**

I find some ["enable_profile_selector"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) options in API Documentation.

```
enable_profile_selector: prompt the user to grant permission for one or more Pages.
```

Is it helps me to achieve my goal?

Any help would be appreciable...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you could list the pages to let the user choose and then use the `place` field in the `data` hash. Do you want to show a FB dialog or something on the other hand?

Comment: Yes, i want to show a dialog box with all pages list where user can select any page. Can you please tell me something more about "place field".